# What mix of corporate structures (out of the 4 given) would be most efficient for a galaxy-wide corporate conglomerate?

Tags: science-fiction, economy

I've been debating how to structure the leadership of a faction for a game, and I'm unsure as to how to organize this corporation. Here's the ground facts I have about the corporation and the universe it's in:

- The organization preceding this corporation was initially formed as a result of highly-increased pirate attacks on trade ships and civilian ships throughout the galaxy.
- This corporation is a conglomerate of companies in a number of trade and protection-related industries, but mainly trading, mining, manufacturing, mercenaries (or private military companies if you prefer), and shipping.
- This company formed in order to keep up with the changing relations of various solar system and multi-solar-system governments, protect their investments on various worlds, and maintain safe, stable trading routes against pirate attacks.
- As the company has several mercenary companies under its umbrella, they also loan out mercenaries to anyone who can pay for them, including the other factions.
- The setting itself is as hard as the average sci-fi (think Star Wars), while there's a running theme of a dark cyberpunk theme for the cities and other locations.
- There is FTL communication through a system of satellites or some other structures supporting the Internet analogue in the story. Most communication devices can access it (much like modern smartphones).

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_structure) might be a good starting point. If there's any other information that might help narrow suggestions, just ask for it and I'll be happy to add information to my post.

4 Models from wiki article

- Functional structure
  This model is commonly used in single-program organizations. It is basically the standard structure mentioned earlier, which is organized around departments. This structure is most appropriate for all small organizations.
- Divisional structure
  Divisional structures are also called product structures because they are based on a certain product or project. This structure is most common in multi-service organizations. Normally, it's based on the departments divided in the firm.
- Geographic structure
  Geographic structures are used in multi-site organizations and are frequently used by networks across different geographic areas.
- Matrix structure
  The Matrix structure is probably the most complicated model of them all because it is organized around multiple dimensions (e.g. geography and product), typically with more than one supervisor. This structure is commonly used in very large organizations because a greater volume requires greater co-ordination. However, this structure is very difficult to manage so it is usually better to reconsider its use and replace it with a different type of structure, then compensate for the tradeoffs.

Comment: What about the *4 given* corporate structures?

Comment: I believe the author was referring to four standard models in the linked article.

Comment: @Tashus that is persumably right, and the edit shows that it is right indeed; still though, anything that is strictly relevant for the question should be either typed out in said question or contained in a picture hosted via the StackExchange imgur account - so it will be always available for reference. Anyone could at anytime edit the linked article and invalidate any answers

Comment: The answer partially depends on the degree of control the corporation has over all of it's 'subsidiaries'. If the corporation is like a loose confederation for mutual defense, the corporation would probably be a division structure, where the 'defense division' concentrated on coordinating defense against piracy, and other 'subsidiary' companies would continue to attempt to maximize their profit. If the corporation is tightly coupled/controlling it would probably be a functional structure, where the prime purpose would be to defend against/exterminate pirates, in spite of lack of profits.

Comment: What is your definition of efficiency for the corporation? Maximum pirate deaths or maximum profit? You can do both, but one is more important to the corporation than the other. Maximum profit means allowing local divisions to vary from an optimized defense plan to make (more) money. Maximizing military efficiency means higher taxes and directing resources from profit making to ramp up their battleship production (more like a government than a corporation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Matrix would be the most likely choice.

"The Matrix structure is probably the most complicated model of them all because it is organized around multiple dimensions (e.g. geography and product), typically with more than one supervisor. This structure is commonly used in very large organizations because a greater volume requires greater co-ordination. However, this structure is very difficult to manage so it is usually better to reconsider its use and replace it with a different type of structure, then compensate for the tradeoffs."

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_structure

On a galactic scale, the conglomerate will probably have to operate as a business group, with affiliated but independently operating companies. Here's an article explaining some differences between business groups and single multi-division companies:

https://hbr.org/2013/12/why-conglomerates-thrive-outside-the-us

Comment: Was going to write an answer but most of it ended up sounding an awful lot like what Tashus had already written. Business Group / Subsidiaries would be a huge logistical boon to this mega corporation. (While also shielding them from legal liability; heres looking at you PMCs)